# An Application which fetches IIS and App Pool details of website hosted in remote server

Tags: asp.net, .net, c#-4.0, iis-7

I got a task of creating an Web application in C# ,which fetches IIS and App Pool details of Website hosted in the remote server(same location).Any idea or help is well appreciated!!!

-Renji

Comment: i didnt get a clue yet,Ali.Where to start and all :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is somehow a broad question, but in order to help here are some points you can start from:

1. get the website name at IIS: `System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.ApplicationHost.GetSiteName()`
2. to get the list of websites and virtual dirs, check this: [How to programmatically get sites list and virtual dirs in IIS 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2555668/how-to-programmatically-get-sites-list-and-virtual-dirs-in-iis-7)
3. to manage IIS: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/99634/Use-C-to-manage-IIS
4. get IIS version: [How to detect IIS version using C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/446390/how-to-detect-iis-version-using-c)
5. get site status: [Programmatically get site status from IIS, gets back COM error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13718128/programmtically-get-site-status-from-iis-gets-back-com-error)

I guess this is enough for you to start exploring everything related to IIS, hope it helps.

Comment: Thanksa lot  Ali for the help.Let me go through the above points and will get back to you,if anything shows up.

Comment: you are welcome, please let me know if u need further assistance

Answer (score 0):

I was also having the same requirement. On doing so many trail and error approach I got the result.

### Pre-Requisites

- IIS 6 and Above
- .Net Framework 4.0 and Above
- Add reference to -System.DirectoryServices and Microsoft.Web.Administration

### c# Console Application Method

```
public static SortedDictionary<string,string> GetApplicationPoolNames ( string mname = null )
    {
        try
        {
            ServerManager manager = new ServerManager ();
            SortedDictionary<string,string> ApplicationPoolStatus = new SortedDictionary<string,string> ();
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty (mname))
                mname = System.Environment.MachineName;
            string appPoolName = string.Empty;
            manager = ServerManager.OpenRemote (mname);

            ApplicationPoolCollection applicationPoolCollection = manager.ApplicationPools;

            foreach (ApplicationPool applicationPool in applicationPoolCollection)
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty (applicationPool.Name))
                {
                    if (!ApplicationPoolStatus.ContainsKey (applicationPool.Name))
                    {
                        ApplicationPoolStatus.Add (applicationPool.Name,string.Empty);
                    }
                    ApplicationPoolStatus[applicationPool.Name] = applicationPool.State.ToString ();
                }
            }
            return ApplicationPoolStatus;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
```

### ASP.Net Web/MVC Application Method

```
public SortedDictionary<string,string> ShowApplicationPoolDatas ()
    {
        SortedDictionary<string,string> ApplicationPoolStatus = new SortedDictionary<string,string> ();
        var domain = this.HttpContext.Request.Url.Host;
        DirectoryEntry Services = new DirectoryEntry ("IIS://"+ domain + "/W3SVC/APPPOOLS");
        foreach (DirectoryEntry Entry in Services.Children)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty (Entry.Name))
            {
                if (!ApplicationPoolStatus.ContainsKey (Entry.Name))
                {
                    ApplicationPoolStatus.Add (Entry.Name,string.Empty);
                }
            }
            var intStatus = (Int32)Entry.InvokeGet ("AppPoolState");
            switch (intStatus)
            {
                case 2:
                    ApplicationPoolStatus[Entry.Name] = "Running";
                    break;
                case 4:
                    ApplicationPoolStatus[Entry.Name] = "Stopped";
                    break;
                default:
                    ApplicationPoolStatus[Entry.Name] = "Unknown";
                    break;
            }
        }
        return ApplicationPoolStatus;

    }
```